# Kotlin mapping a list that has a list inside

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to map a list of items, that has another list inside which should be mapped into the same type of items. however, i end up having List<List> and can not flatten.

```kotlin
TropicalFruit(
    val someStuff: String
)

Fruits(
    val type: String,
    val tropicalFruits: List<TropicalFruit>
)

FruitUiModel(
    ...
)

val listOfFruits: List<Fruit>

listOfFruits.map { fruit ->
    if (fruit.type == "tropical") {
        tropicalFruits.map {
            FruitUiModel(it.someStuff)
        }
    } else {
        FruitUiModel(fruit.type)
    }

}
```

As a result, I want to achieve a List instead of List
Any being both FruitUiModel and List

So the list ends up being something like listOf(fruitUiModel, fruitUiModel, listOfFruitUiModels)
and i need to flatten the `listOfFruitUiModels`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```kotlin
listOfFruits.flatMap { fruit ->
    if (fruit.type == "tropical") {
       fruit.tropicalFruits.map { FruitUiModel(it.someStuff) }
    } else {
        FruitUiModel(fruit.type)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, made a mistake in the question, updated the last part. btw how do you format code here :D

Comment: I've already reformatted it in my answer, but the change is in the first line. Formatting is a bit clumsy, probably best to copy from an editor.